# elastic search 5.1.1 unable to install elasticsearch-head?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I've just install latest elasticseach on my mac using `brew install elasticsearch`, and it can run and I can see contents from `localhost:9200`.

But I tried to install web-browser for it. So the stack over flow says there's a "plugin" command under `elasticsearch/bin` folder. But seems this is an answer for very old version of Elasticsearch. Now there's only one `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/5.1.1/libexec/bin/elasticsearch-plugin`, and I failed to:

```
elasticsearch-plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

It's not successful. But how to achieve it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Andrei said, you may install another standalone tool called `cerebro`: https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro

It's from the same author who developed the [`kopf` plugin](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf) back then for previous ES releases (2.x and backwards).

Basically, the exact same UI as the Kopf plugin, but as a standalone Scala app.

[image: Cerebro]

Answer (score 1):

`elasticsearch-head` is not supported in ES 5.x anymore. See here more details about this: https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head#running-as-a-plugin-of-elasticsearch-deprecated

> for Elasticsearch 5.x: site plugins are not supported. Run as a standalone server

And you need to use it with the [standalone server option](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head#running-with-built-in-server).