# Installing kopf - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I make the download of elasticsearch-kopf and unzip the path , so i put the path kopf in usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/

When i do this my elasticsearch stop running, but when i delete the path running correct, why is wrong the kopf path?

Comment: What version of ES are you running?

Comment: Version ES: 5.4.1

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680260/elastic-search-5-1-1-unable-to-install-elasticsearch-head/43680492#43680492

Answer (score 1):

i too tried the same , installing kopf in elastic search,
finaly i have comes to know that kopf no longer maintained, instead use [cerebro](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro)

[image]